# For $A = \{ 1, 5, 10, 12\} $ List the complete set for $ S = \{a+b : a \in A, b \in A \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $A = \{ 1, 5, 10, 12\} $ List the complete set for 
$$ S = \{a+b : a \in A, b \in A \}$$

I need help figuring out this answer. I thought it would be adding every combination of the numbers to each other, so something like
$$1 + 5 = 6$$
$$ 1+ 10 = 11$$
$$ 1 +12 = 13$$
$$ 5 + 10 = 15$$
$$ 5 +12 = 17$$
$$10 + 12 = 22$$
and then also adding the numbers to themselves
$$ 1 + 1 = 2$$
$$ 5+ 5 = 10$$
$$10 + 10 = 20$$
$$12 +12 = 24$$
for $$S = \{ 6, 11, 13, 15, 17, 22, 2 ,10, 20, 24 \}$$ but this answer is wrong and I am not sure what the right answer is

Comment: Seems right to me

Comment: Is that 5 in the solution supposed to be a 10?

Comment: @Blavius it sure is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer seems right to me, if you are submitting it through internet, try rearrange it, from small to big.